# SELECT field value minus previous field value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a select query that gets a CarID, month, mileage and CO2 emission. 
Now it gives for each month per car the mileage like this:

```
month 1: 5000
month 2: 5200
...
```

What I really need is that it takes the current value minus the previous one. I get data between a certain time frame and I already included a mileage point before that time frame. So it would be possible to get the total miles per month, I just don't know how. What I want is this.

```
pre timeframe:  5000
month 1:        200
month 2:        150
...
```

How would I do this?

edit: code, I have not yet tried anything as I have no clue how to start to do this.

```
    resultlist as (
SELECT
    CarID
,   '01/01/2000' as beginmonth
,   MAX(kilometerstand) as Kilometers
,   MAX(Co2Emission) as CO2
FROM
    totalmileagelist
GROUP BY CarID

UNION

SELECT
    CarID
,   beginmonth
,   MAX(kilometerstand) as Kilometers
,   MAX(Co2Emission) as CO2
FROM
resultunionlist
GROUP BY CarID, beginmonth
)

select * from resultlist
order by CarID, beginmonth
```

Edit2: explanation to the code

In the first part of the result list I grab the latest mileage per car. In the second part, after the union, I grab per month per car the latest mileage.

Comment: share your table schema and query you tried

Comment: Added it. I haven't tried the query yet as I have no clue where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to subtract the previous milage, use the `lag()` function:

```
select ml.*,
       (kilometerstand - lag(kilometerstand) over (partition by carid order by month)
       ) as diff
from totalmileagelist ml;
```

`lag()` is available in SQL Server 2012+.  In earlier versions you can use a correlated subquery or `outer apply`.

(I missed the version because it is in the title and not on a tag.)  In SQL Server 2008:

```
select ml.*,
       (ml.mileage - mlprev.mileage) as diff
from totalmileagelist ml outer apply
     (select top 1 ml2.*
      from totalmileagelist ml2
      where ml2.CarId = ml.CarId and
            ml2.month < ml.month
      order by ml2.month desc
     ) mlprev;
```

Comment: I am using SQL server 2008, I'll take a look at outer apply. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
SELECT id, yourColumnValue,
       COALESCE(
       (
       SELECT TOP 1 yourColumnValue
       FROM table_name t
       WHERE t.id> tbl.id
       ORDER BY
             rowInt
       ), 0) - yourColumnValue AS diff
FROM  table_name tbl
ORDER BY
      id
```

or like this using `rank()`

```
select  rank() OVER (ORDER BY id) as 'RowId', mileage into temptable 
from totalmileagelist 

select t1.mileage - t2.mileage from temptable t1, temptable t2 
where t1.RowId = t2.RowId - 1

drop table temptable
```